# mvc 4 connect to external web service

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an asp.net application from scratch using mvc 4.
One of the requirements that were given to me was to connect to a web service,
and call 2 search methods from it, but they only provided me the .svc route of
the web service.

```
http://server/servicefolder/service.svc
```

I have made some searches here and there , and haven't figured it out yet, where
do I have to start or anything.

I would like if someone can give me some help as where to start looking, doing, any tip
or recomendations also would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a service reference to `http://server/servicefolder/service.svc`

[image]

Once you've added the reference, initialize the client side proxy, e.g.

```
var client = new YourServiceName.YourServiceNameClient(); // Look for the client object.

client.YourClientMethod(...);  // Call the method defined in the client.
```

Comment: yeah I do that, and how do I use the service inside please.